# Determine parent ProcessID in Word when launched via Office Automation

Tags: c++, process, ms-word, ole, pid

This is a bit arcane, so I hope I am being clear.

I have a custom, unmanaged DLL: MYDLL.DLL, that is invoked by Word via a VBA script using Declare Function.

The DLL uses CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to get the Parent ProcessID. I.e., the process that invoked Winword.exe.

It works fine in most situations. For example,

- If I double-click on the DOCX file, it shows the parent PID as Explorer.exe.
- If I "Start" the document from a CMD window, it shows the parent PID as CMD.EXE.
- If I launch Winword.exe from my application, MYAPP.EXE, using ShellExecute, it shows the Parent PID as MYAPP.EXE.

So far, so good.

However, if MYAPP.EXE opens the DOCX file via OLE / Office Automation, it shows the Parent PID as SVCHOST.EXE.  MYAPP.EXE is nowhere in the ancestor chain as far as I can see.

Is there any way I can tell what the invoking PID is when launched via OLE / Office Automation?

Comment: This is because the Office Automation is an out-of-process COM object. It likely has no awareness of your process.

Comment: Right. But the invoking PID must be available somewhere?